# How to find out classes with highest number of dependent classes in IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I want to improve the unit test coverage of a certain project. In order to do this, I need to find out, what classes are the most important ones.

By "important" I mean the number of classes, which use a particular class (including transitive dependencies).

How can I find it out (number of dependent classes for every class in a project) in IntelliJ Idea?

I tried to install JDepend plugin, but it seems outdated.

Comment: To improve your code coverage you need to write tests for all you classes.  The number of dependencies does matter.  In fact class which have already been well used and tested don't need the tests as urgently.  I would start with the classes rarely called.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Writing tests for all classes isn't possible from economic point of view. So I have to prioritize - write tests for the most important classes first.

Comment: I would focus on the classes which are the greatest source of issue/bugs in your system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could inspect your code with Dependency issues inspection changing the threshold value for dependencies count. Both direct and transitive deps are supported.